# java write netstat in cmd

Tags: java, cmd, netstat

My goal is to print all the internet connections on my computer. When I type `netstat` on CMD, I get the internet connections list. I wanted to do the same in Java, automatically.

My code:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
process = runtime.exec(pathToCmd);
byte[] command1array = command1.getBytes(); // writing netstat in an array of bytes
OutputStream out = process.getOutputStream();
out.write(command1array);
out.flush();
out.close();
readCmd();  //read and print cmd
```

But with this code I get `C:\eclipse\workspace\Tracker>Mais?` instead of the list of connections. Obviously I'm working with Eclipse, in Windows 7. What am I doing wrong? I've looked in similar topics but I couldn't find what's wrong. Thank you for the answers.

EDIT:

```
public static void readCmd() throws IOException {
    is = process.getInputStream();
    isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime` and you need to show us `readCmd()`. the error probably lies in there.

Comment: alright, `readCmd` seems ok. maybe just try to use a `PrintWriter` wrapping your `OutputStream`. I also encountered this problem some time ago. Still don't know, why that happens.

Comment: How is `command1` defined?

Comment: public static String command1 ="netstat";

Comment: "Obviously i'm working with eclipse, in windows 7" - how is that obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : I was able to create a file in my default temporary directory with all the connections

```
final String cmd = "netstat -ano";

        try {

            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

            InputStream in = process.getInputStream();

            File tmp = File.createTempFile("allConnections","txt");

            byte[] buf = new byte[256];

            OutputStream outputConnectionsToFile = new FileOutputStream(tmp);

            int numbytes = 0;

            while ((numbytes = in.read(buf, 0, 256)) != -1) {

                outputConnectionsToFile.write(buf, 0, numbytes);

            }

            System.out.println("File is present at "+tmp.getAbsolutePath());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
```

Comment: You forgot to close the file.

Answer (score 0):

File [NETSTAT.EXE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat) should be on the [PATH](https://cs1331.gitlab.io/environment-variables.html) (environment variable), hence your "command" of just *netstat* should be enough. If `NETSTAT.EXE` is not on the PATH, you can either edit the PATH or provide the full path to the file in your Java code. On my Windows 10 machine, the path to the file is...

```
C:\Windows\System32\NETSTAT.EXE
```

You should also use class [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) rather than class `Runtime`. Since JDK 7, class `ProcessBuilder` has method `inheritIO`. Hence if all you want is to print the output of `netstat`, the following is the simplest code to achieve that. Note that the below code works because file `NETSTAT.EXE` is on the PATH.

```java
import java.io.IOException;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("netstat");
        pb.inheritIO();
        try {
            pb.start();
        }
        catch (IOException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the first few lines of output that are displayed when I run the above code.

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5354         BDL-DLRC88V:49669      ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use an instance of [**`java.util.Scanner`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read the output of the command.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] cmdarray = { "netstat", "-o" };
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(process.getInputStream(), "IBM850");
    sc.useDelimiter("\\A");
    System.out.println(sc.next());
    sc.close();
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't parsing the output, it is getting the correct output, i.e. running the correct command.

Answer (score -2):

```
final String cmd = "netstat -ano";

    try {

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

        InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(line);
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    } finally{
        in  = null;
        isr = null;
        br = null;
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.