# Get the IP Adresses of other apps connected to the internet in Android?

Tags: android, ip-address, sniffer

I would like to get the IP addresses of different android apps which are connected to the internet. E.g. Google Play services is connected to 173.194.39.8. Or Internet app is connected to xxx.xxx.xx.x. 
I know that it is possible. But I am not sure how I can receive these IP addresses. How can I get them? Do I need root access? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "ip addresses of other apps"? Or do you mean something like "netstat"?

Comment: Yes, I mean something like "netstat". I would like to get the IP addresses so that I can get the domain which fits to this address.

Comment: Why not run "netstat"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735379/java-write-netstat-in-cmd

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632314/android-progamatically-determine-list-of-apps-that-have-a-tcp-connection-open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not run "netstat" via command line?

Check this question out: [java write netstat in cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735379/java-write-netstat-in-cmd).

Simply Google searches bring up similar "netstat" implementations in Java:

https://github.com/hyperic/sigar/blob/master/bindings/java/src/org/hyperic/sigar/cmd/Netstat.java

and

https://gitorious.org/networklog/networklog/source/60cb640ac27f8b4fb06f11d9d81c94591a531862:src/com/googlecode/networklog/NetStat.java

Comment: But how can I figure out to which App this belongs to?

Comment: What do you mean? Net Stat can get you started. I do not have an exact solution for showing individual IPs for an app. You might be able to map the PIDs with IP addresses.